# What is the etymological history behind the mathematical "induction" versus the philosophical "inductive [reasoning]"?

Tags: etymology, history, mathematics, academia, contemporary-english

Was talking about it in a (particularly off topic) university lecture on Emperical reasoning (deductive - our logic-math course, vs inductive - "gravity gets taken for granted"). A reason we were talking a lot about it was because our course has a lot of content on "proof by induction". Which is odd, as the inductive proofs aren't just "well it happened 50 times, itll happen a 51th time"; they're more of our deductive reasoning we've applied.

So maybe "etymology" being the question of what separates the two is less specific than the "history". But I don't know anyway, that's why I'm asking a question!! :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question?

Comment: This is the same word used for effectively the same meaning in two similar fields.  There is no mystery.

Comment: I don't think you understand the meaning of *inductive* in *inductive proof*.

Comment: This sounds like it could be an intersting question but it is very hard to follow you. Can you rework this into an answerable question?

Comment: It _is_ confusing. But note that mathematical induction, is really a form of _deduction_. Once you get used to that, life gets easier.

Comment: @Mitch Re-reading my own post, **I'm so sorry** to the 28 views that suffered through that clusterfunk. The question I _meant_ to ask/formulate was along the lines of: "What is the reason, historically/etymologically, that the deductive reasoning field of discrete mathematics' has a deductive proof called 'inductive proof'?"

Comment: Then: 
(**1**) should I delete this post and re-submit it better worded? Or 
(**2**) is anyone willing/able to edit my original post to reflect what I commented in above in a better way than I just did? 
I'm not sure of what's polite.

Comment: _edit_: I'm just going to move on, I think, as my question is way too specific/might be in the wrong place, even. I've accepted @Barmar 's answer below because he had a good answer for what I haphazardly asked before. Sorry y'all. Nothing to see here, move on...

Comment: @enche Maybe the question then is "When was the deductive principle of mathematical induction first labeled so"? Or some variant thereof. And this would get likely more informative answers on mathematics.SE or history of science and math.SE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both uses of *induction* refer to generalizing a principle from a collection of individual facts that support it. For instance, after seeing the sun rise every day for some period of time, we intuitively conclude that it will keep rising -- this is inductive reasoning, not deductive. By contrast, deductive reasoning works from general principles to determine specific facts; examples are the proofs of plane geometry that are derived from Euler's postulates.

Mathematical proofs by induction are a formalization of inductive reasoning. Rather than concluding intuitively that the sequence will continue as it previously has, we determine a relationship between the items in the sequence that guarantees this.

It's true that inductive proofs are actually a form of deductive reasoning, because the rules applied are general principles. So the relationship is somewhat metaphoric: it's called induction because it involves a sequence, much like the sequences we generalize from in my first paragraph above.

Comment: Good news: this is a great answer, thank you for your effort! Bad news: as talked about in the new comments on the original post, I'm a buffoon in asking clearly. What I meant to ask was not "what is the difference or reason...", but more "how did this end up being the norm historically"... I'm just going to take this answer though, as it is really good, and I don't think I'm going to luck out with any discrete mathematics-philosophy-etymology hybrid experts posting. Sorry to you and all your (helpful!) effort though! Everybody gets an upvote! If anybody has info specific stuff, PM me?